# PHP7.4.0 RC1 - unrecognized options running ./configure

Tags: php, configure, php-7.4

I recently compiled php 7.4.0 RC1 on my mac, however running `./configure` (with some parameters) I get the following warning:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-libxml, --with-pcre-regex, --with-gd, --enable-opcache-file, --with-pdo, --enable-wddx
```

I understand what the warning itself means, but what those parameter got replaced with or why they are not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `configure --help` to see what options are available. It appears these have been removed or renamed.

- `--enable-libxml` should be `--with-libxml`, which is the default anyway, and doesn't need to be specified.
- `--with-pdo` should be `--enable-pdo`.
- `--with-gd` should be `--enable-gd`.
- `--with-pcre-regex` has been removed. It is always enabled (and has always been).
- `--enable-opcache-file` has been removed. It is always enabled if opcache is enabled.
- [WDDX was removed for 7.4.0](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.4.0RC1/NEWS).